# How to invert a pandas dataframe idxmax() filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a situation like the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'group':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2'],'cycle':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3],'value':[4,5,6,7,2,5,4]})

df

  group cycle   value
0   1   1   4
1   1   2   5
2   1   3   6
3   1   4   7
4   2   1   2
5   2   2   5
6   2   3   4
```

I can get the value corresponding with the maximum cycle in each group using the following

```
idx=df.groupby('group')['cycle'].idxmax()

df.loc[idx]['value']

3    7
6    4
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

However what I really need is to invert the idx filter and get every value which does not correspond to the maximum cycle for each group, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are not duplicated maximal values per groups is possible create mask for compare maximal values per groups with came column with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` for select column in one step:

```
m = df.groupby('group')['cycle'].transform('max').ne(df['cycle'])

s = df.loc[m, 'value']
print (s)
0    4
1    5
2    6
4    2
5    5
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Your solution is changed by remove double `[]` and [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
idx = df.groupby('group')['cycle'].idxmax()
s = df.loc[df.index.difference(idx), 'value']
print (s)
0    4
1    5
2    6
4    2
5    5
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Output is different if multiple maximal values per groups, because `transform` solution remove all maximals and `idxmax` only first maximal:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'group':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2'],
                 'cycle':[1,2,3,4,3,2,3],
                 'value':[4,5,6,7,2,5,4]})
print (df)
  group  cycle  value
0     1      1      4
1     1      2      5
2     1      3      6
3     1      4      7
4     2      3      2 <- double max values per group 2
5     2      2      5
6     2      3      4
```

---

```
m = df.groupby('group')['cycle'].transform('max').ne(df['cycle'])
s = df.loc[m, 'value']
print (s)
0    4
1    5
2    6
5    5
Name: value, dtype: int64

idx = df.groupby('group')['cycle'].idxmax()
s = df.loc[df.index.difference(idx), 'value']
print (s)
0    4
1    5
2    6
5    5
6    4
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Apologies I just realised there was a slight error in my question, which I've now clarified. The clarification is that I need to identify the values corresponding to all the cycles which are not the maximum cycle value, rather than the maximum from the values column.

Comment: @dsbbsd9 - Principe is same, answer was edited.